# How can you see Heroku logs for git deployed app on Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

If we deploy app normally on heroku-cli, we can easily see all the logs by using

```
$ heroku logs
```

But how can we check heroku logs if we have connected the heroku app with git repository, then we can't use heroku logs

Comment: Do you mean using Heroku's GitHub integration? Standard Heroku deployment uses Git too (via `git push`). In any case, that shouldn't affect the `heroku logs` command. What happens when you try running it?

Comment: Please describe your full error. No matter how you deploy the app, you will be able to see it's logs with the `heroku logs` command.

Comment: It will say ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass your application name

`heroku logs --tail --app <application-name>`